# specify cqlsh output timezone

Tags: cassandra, timestamp, cqlsh

I have a table in cassandra with a datatype of timestamp. i am using cqlsh to get data out of the database and wanted to change the output format for how my timestamp column output looks like. I researched around and found that i can change the timestamp output format by making changes to the following file:

- ~/.cassandra/cqlshrc

But i learnt that the only change i can make is the time elements, i cannot make the output to display my timestamps in a different timezone(say UTC). It always displays the timestamps in my local timezone.

**I wanted to know if there is a way i could make cqlsh display timestamp in my desired time zone, or atleast in UTC zone.** 
Any help or pointers are appreciated.

I'm using the following versions:
cqlsh 4.1.1 | Cassandra 2.0.6 | CQL spec 3.1.1

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can change your environment variable to get show timezone:

```
TZ=America/Los_Angeles cqlsh -k mpj `hostname` -e 'select time from userbehavior limit 3'

 time
--------------------------
 2015-02-15 21:17:03-0800
 2015-02-15 18:16:21-0800
 2015-02-15 00:04:52-0800

(3 rows)
```

and:

```
TZ=UTC cqlsh -k mpj `hostname` -e 'select time from userbehavior limit 3'

 time
--------------------------
 2015-02-16 05:17:03+0000
 2015-02-16 02:16:21+0000
 2015-02-15 08:04:52+0000

(3 rows)
```

Comment: its really a neat trick to get things done. Thanks for your inputs.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working for me. I used 
[ui]
TZ = IST .
But it is showing times appended by +0000. 
  What's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The cqlshrc timeout option configures the output format of database objects using Python strftime syntax according to http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/cqlsh.html.  I haven't verified that these strftime directives work, but if you're willing to experiment try using the strftime() directive %z (UTC offset in the form +HHMM or -HHMM and %Z (time zone name). See https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Both these options work the same way and just show the time zone.
I wanted something that can help me output the date in a different time zone(or atleast UTC), not local time zone.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the question. Here is just an alternative way, which is do some date operation after you fetch the data using "**datetime.timedelta()**". You can calculate the offset time from UTC, and then do a date adjust. Just for your reference.

```
>>> import datetime 
>>> offset = -10 # in hours
>>> original = '08/19/2015 10:59' 
>>> adjusted = datetime.datetime.strptime(original, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M') + datetime.timedelta(hours=offset) 
>>> print adjusted.strftime('%m/%d/%Y %H:%M') 
    08/19/2015 00:59
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change default timezone of local cqlsh  by editing ~/.cassandra/cqlshrc

Ex :

[ui]
TZ = IST