# Cannot change timezone in Cassandra 2.1.11 to IST

Tags: cassandra, timezone, cqlsh, cassandra-2.1

I am inserting the data from C# to Cassandra cluster in IST (`'2015-12-28'`) format. But when i query the same data using `cqlsh`. It gives me in `'2015-12-27 18:30:00+0000'` format. So, to change the format i have tried some of the suggestion but couldn't get succeed like addition of TZ='IST' in cqlshrc file. [specify cqlsh output timezone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26595649/specify-cqlsh-output-timezone)

So, how to change the timezone to be IST and get the value like this `'2015-12-27 05:30:00+0000'`.

Comment: Have you tried using the actual time zone ID instead of IST? Try `TZ=Asia/Kolkata` (It's not clear why you put the quotes round IST either...)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cassandra : CQLSH not displaying correct timezone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32778433/cassandra-cqlsh-not-displaying-correct-timezone)

Answer (score 1):

making cqlsh to display timestamp in local timezone. Install pytz

```
sudo apt-get install python-tz
```

And then configure cqlshrc file where we can specify timezone and output time format

```
nano .cassandra/cqlshrc
[ui]
timezone = Asia/Kolkata
time_format = %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%z
```

Comment: hi, could you please tell how to set time to 12 hour format. by default it is showing 24 hour format

Comment: use %h (instead of %H) for 12-hour format. Also refer python examples.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following time_format as required

yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm,
 yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss,
 yyyy-mm-dd HH:mmZ,
 yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ssZ,
 yyyy-mm-dd'T'HH:mm,
 yyyy-mm-dd'T'HH:mmZ,
 yyyy-mm-dd'T'HH:mm:ss,
 yyyy-mm-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ,
 yyyy-mm-dd,
 yyyy-mm-ddZ,

by setting the time_format property in the [ui] section of the cqlshrc file.