# Cassandra cqlsh and Datastax timestamp difference

Tags: cassandra, datastax, cqlsh

- I've observed that there are some differences between cqlsh and datastax devcenter when selecting timestamps. Cqlsh shows it in 24 hours system, datastax in 12 hours system. How to understand this properly? Is it any way to show timestamps in Datastax DevCenter in 24 hours system?
- Cassandra Server stores date in 24-hours or in 12-hours system? After the ":" sign there is "0000", where are my miliseconds? It is possible to store them in Cassandra?

Some screenshots:
cqlsh:

[image: cqlsh]

datastax devcenter:

[image: datastax]

Answer (score 0):

The underlying stored data will just be the timestamp and you can configure how this gets represented when you read it.

See this link for editing the timezone displayed in DevCenter. You might have something in the .ini configuring DevCenter for 12 hour time.

https://docs.datastax.com/en/latest-devcenter/devcenter/timestampFormat.html

There's also this post which has some tips if you want to customise how cqlsh displays the time [specify cqlsh output timezone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26595649/specify-cqlsh-output-timezone)