# cassandra timestamp format difference in version 2.1.7 and 3.1

Tags: cassandra, datastax, datastax-enterprise, datastax-java-driver, cassandra-2.1

I am trying to migrate my data from **cassandra 2.1.7 to 3.10.**

I have this following table in both Cassandra versions (`2.1.7 and 3.10`)

```
CREATE TABLE timestamp_test ( name text PRIMARY KEY, time timestamp )
```

When I am inserting data in this above table in both cassandra versions using below query :

```
INSERT INTO timestamp_test(name , time ) VALUES ( 'ppaa', '2017-03-18 20:38:03+0530');
```

I found that both version of cassandra saves data in different format for timestamp cloumn i.e `time`

Cassandra 2.1.7

```
 name | time
------+--------------------------
 ppaa | 2017-03-18 20:38:03+0530
```

Cassandra 3.1

```
name | time
------+---------------------------------
 ppaa | 2017-03-18 15:08:03.000000+0000
```

**Is their any way I can save `timestamp` in cassandra v3.1 in format `2017-03-18 20:38:03+0530` i.e (similart to cassandra v2.1.7)**

Comment: Both the timestamp is correct, second one is just showing in GMT timezone

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see without timezone information, you can modify cqlshrc file ( conf folder).
Follow this link as well. [specify cqlsh output timezone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26595649/specify-cqlsh-output-timezone).